# Elementor Widget - repeater responsive margin control doesn't work

Tags: controls, responsive, elementor

I've got some trouble with creating repeater responsive margin control in my Elementor widget. I dynamically create items in the widget and I need this field to be able to change the position of my items in the widget.

My code below doesn't work.

```
    // Content section
    $this->start_controls_section(
        'content_section',
        [
            'label' => __( 'Content', 'watt-elements' ),
            'tab' => Controls_Manager::TAB_CONTENT,
        ]
    );

    ...

    $repeater = new \Elementor\Repeater();


    $repeater->add_responsive_control(
       'feature_margin',
          [
             'label' => __( 'Feature margin', 'plugin-name' ),
             'type' => \Elementor\Controls_Manager::DIMENSIONS,
             'size_units' => [ 'px', 'em', '%' ],
             'selectors' => [
             '{{WRAPPER}} {{CURRENT_ITEM}} .feature-tip' => 'margin: {{TOP}}{{UNIT}} {{RIGHT}}{{UNIT}} {{BOTTOM}}{{UNIT}} {{LEFT}}{{UNIT}};',
          ],



    ]);

    ...

    $this->end_controls_section();
```

Comment: Have solved the problem? Here you would need to add dynamic class with js each function to the CURRENT_ITEMs. Then you can add the css style to them from Elementor editor.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a late reply but should be helpful for someone.
You need to add the below dynamic class for {{CURRENT_ITEM}}.

```
class="elementor-repeater-item-<?php echo $item['_id']; ?>"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I've fixed this problem by reading carefully Elementor documentation.